# Create class instances from a file in Python

Tags: python, file, class

I am trying to create class instances from a file of objects:

```
MyCube,2,3,4
FancyCube,5,3,3
AngryCube,5,5,5
```

where the first column is the name of the instance.

```
class cube(object):
   def __init__( self, X, Y, Z):
      self.X = X
      self.Y = Y
      self.Z = Z


def filetest():
   filename = 'CubeDB.txt'
   ins = open(filename, 'r')

   for line in ins:
       name, X, Y, Z = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
       vars()[name] = cube(X, Y, Z)

filetest()
print MyCube.X
```

I've been hacking at this for awhile and the above is the closest I implementation I can find but I get this error:

```
File "classtest.py", line 21, in filetest
    vars()[name] = cube(X, Y, Z)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: My guess is that `vars` is set to a string somewhere above `cube`

Comment: Why not split the line up into pieces to see which of the two function calls is raising? `c = cube(X, Y, Z)`, `v = vars()`, and `v[name] = c`. Then, instead of us having to _guess_ what went wrong, you'll _know_.

Comment: First of all it's a bad idea to use `vars()`, secondly `vars()` inside a function will not create a global variable.

Comment: Trying to create objects dynamically like this is almost always a [bad](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) [idea](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). And relying on modifying `vars()` to do it is an even worse idea. Why not just pass around a `dict` mapping cube names to cubes?

Comment: @abarnert That's your own post I guess. ;-)

Comment: @hcwhsa: One link is Ned Batchelder's post, the other is mine. He explains a lot of things more clearly and more concisely than me. and either post is better than I could explain in an SO comment…

Comment: When I copy and paste your data file and your code and run it, I do not get this error. (I do, of course, get a _different_ error, because `MyCube` isn't defined anywhere except in a copy of the locals of `filetest`, but that's a different issue.) Without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that actually demonstrates your problem, nobody can debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been suggested in the comments, modifying `vars()` might not be the best approach. I would suggest to create a dictionary and use the names of the cubes as keys. Besides, you can use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) directly:

```
import csv

class Cube(object):
    def __init__(self, X, Y, Z):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.Z = Z

def filetest():
    filename = 'CubeDB.txt'
    cubes = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
            cubes[row[0]] = Cube(*row[1:])
    return cubes

cubes = filetest()
print cubes['MyCube'].X
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the csv module existed. That solved my problem and works great.